# Is perception presentational or representational?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Is perception presentational or representational? If you assume it is representational then sensory motor emulation (mental imagery, counter-factual rehearsal, anticipation, goal planning, etc. (Grush, Barsalou, Kosslyn, Anderson, et al.) becomes re-representational. This seems terminologically awkward.

Comment: I'm ignorant of what other people have written. I don't know if I'm even welcome here for that reason.  But FWIW I do not believe perception is representational; if by representational you mean that there are things "out there" and there's a perception apparatus, like a DSLR sensor, that records a representation of what's "out there." Personally I believe that we can not separate our experience from the outside world at all. I don't believe you can separate subject/object when it comes to our perceptions. Early sensory deprivation subjects went crazy for example. What's "out there" is us.

Comment: There's no reason for the second re. Representations can easily be of representations. But in actuality the second representation will be of the image conceived in the process of the first representation. Or at least that's how I understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

it is representential with respect to a presentation we percieve(the thing in itself), and motor emulation is a re-reprentation with respect to the presentation we percieve, but a representation with respect to presentation* which we percieve with our senses.
*: which is itself a representation of the presentation (the thing in itself)we percieve.
here I assume a dualistic view, which is subject to several doubts, maybe we can consume that all is representation and perceiving a presentation is not the case anymore.